# Parameter checking in Transact-SQL (SQL Server 2008): IF/OR/raiserror syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I currently have this snippet of code which checks that an input variable is within a certain range:

```
IF (@vThingID < 17 OR @vThingID > 16381)
BEGIN
    raiserror('Thing ID out of range: must be between 17 and 16381')
    RETURN
END
```

This is T-SQL code that is inside a stored procedure. The error message, on "compiling" to a stored procedure, is this:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server ****-***, Procedure np*************, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I've tried changing all the syntax- removing the parentheses, taking out the OR statement, putting semicolons after certain lines, etc. It just doesn't seem to make any difference, and I can't spot any syntax errors here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The severity and state of the `RAISERROR` function are not optional. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) and decide which values make the most sense for you.

Comment: Be sure to up-vote useful answers (click on the up-arrow next to the answer) and select the best answer (click on the check-mark) so that other people searching about this problem in the future can quickly identify the best answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (@vThingID < 17 OR @vThingID > 16381)
BEGIN
    raiserror('Thing ID out of range: must be between 17 and 16381', 10, 11)
    RETURN
END
```